# how to declare const which can be initialized at runtime only

Tags: c#

My class contains `LOT_SIZE` constant which can not be changed. But I can initialize it only during execution, because I obtain `LOT_SIZE` from Securities table at runtime. However I want to make clear that this is constant and I want to protect it from changes from any other places except one "friend" place where I want to initialize it ("Securities" table read).

Do we have something for that in C# or I just have to use `LOT_SIZE` as regular variable?

I can not declare `LOT_SIZE` as `readonly` because during object construction "Securities" table still not read and so I don't know `LOT_SIZE` value.

Comment: [readonly (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7(v=vs.100).aspx) - can't you read the Securities table before initializing your class?

Comment: You could transform in a regular **private** variable inside a class, then give only a property get accessor to the variable

Comment: Could `LOT_SIZE` be a readonly member of the "friend" place? If that's the class that has responsibility for the value, perhaps it should live there.

Comment: @jrummell possible but not trivial, however approach suggested by `mafue` may be used....

Comment: @Steve still will not be clear that this is actually constant

Comment: I don't get it. A constant is always defined at compile time and never changed in code. A readonly could not be used because there is no value for it at the object constructor, I think that your last chance is the read-only property. Perhaps inside a global static class containing other application wide data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is probably to read the value before creating the class that must hold it, so you can pass it into the constructor and put it into a `readonly` field. But as you've excluded doing it the obvious way...

You could use a read-only property (a property with a get but no set) and always access it via the property except in the place where you initially set up the value.

If you don't even want to risk changing it from within your own class, then create a class to "wrap" the value. This class would do nothing more than read the value when required the first time and expose it as a read-only property to your consumer classes.

But whichever way you choose, please don't use "1970's C macro constant" (ALL_CAPS) naming for your constant :-)

Comment: i'm using CAPS because this is default code style in Java which was created only in ~1995 :) http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/constant.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a variable in a way that it can be modified in one place and not in any other (except for readonly which you excluded).

I suggest you use some kind of "lazy pattern". Write a class which wraps a value and allows the value to be set exactly one time. You can make the variable referencing an instance of this class read-only.

```
class WriteOnce<T>
{
 T _val;
 bool _isInitialized;

 public T Value {
  get { if (!_isInitialized) throw; return _val; }
  set { if (_isInitialized) throw; _val = value; }
 }
}

...

class SomeOtherClass {
 readonly WriteOnce<int> LOT_SIZE = new WriteOnce<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class to read from your table with a private member variable (even make the class a Singleton to get uber fancy).  Then make a static public variable with only a getter.  It's a bit overkill, but that would be the only way to allow it to be set after initialization, but only able to be modified the one time.